# Oracle 10: Incomprehensible behaviour on INSERT into a view?

Tags: oracle, view, triggers, oracle10g

we have a strange problem here, we can't explain to ourselves.

We have a view in an Oracle DB Version 10.2.0.5.8. The view uses an INSTEAD OF trigger.

This is the code for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER V1_T1_BIUD
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON V1_T1
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  AnyId   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO Table T1 (
       F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
    ) VALUES (
       :new.F1, :new.F2, :new.F3, :new.F4, :new.F5
    );
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE T1 SET F1 = :new.F1,
                  F2 = :new.F2,
                  F3 = :new.F3,
                  F4 = :new.F4,
                  F5 = :new.F5
    WHERE F1 = :old.F1;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM T1
    WHERE F1 = :old.F1;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

This is an example INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO V_T1 (
  F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
)
SELECT A.V, A.S, A.F, A.T, A.Z
FROM (
  SELECT 'E' V, 'N' S, 'ABC' F, 'E' T, 'E' Z FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'E',   'Y',   'QWE',   'O',   'E'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I',   'Y',   'GHJ',   'I',   'I'   FROM DUAL           
) A
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
COMMIT;
```

Pay attention to the ORDER BY clause at the end of the select. The result of this INSERT statement is something like this:

```
F1 F2 F3  F4 F5
---------------
E  N  ABC I  I 
E  Y  QWE I  I 
I  Y  GHJ I  I
```

As you can see, the 4th and 5th column are incorrectly filled with the values of the last datarow in all other datarows.

If we change the INSERT statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO V_T1 (
  F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
)
SELECT A.V, A.S, A.F, A.T, A.Z
FROM (
  SELECT 'E' V, 'N' S, 'ABC' F, 'E' T, 'E' Z FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'E',   'Y',   'QWE',   'O',   'E'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I',   'Y',   'GHJ',   'I',   'I'   FROM DUAL           
) A
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
COMMIT;
```

the result is this:

```
F1 F2 F3  F4 F5
---------------
E  N  ABC E  E 
E  Y  QWE O  E 
I  Y  GHJ I  I
```

Again, pay attention to the ORDER BY clause, which now orders all rows instead of the first three in the first insert statement.

edit: If you omit the ORDER BY clause the result is also as expected (e. g. like in example 2).

Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

P. S. Concerning the comments:

I have not time to investigate or deliver any more infos on this topic today. I will create a complete example on our database and publish it here in the next few days. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Why is the order by important? Why even have an order by on an insert statement (unless it affects the data inserted)? There is no facility to maintain insertion order.

Comment: That's correct and you are right. There is no need for the order by in an insert. But it still bugs me, why this is happening. :-)

Comment: I see. Does look like a bug (unless your trigger or view does something you did not show). +1

Comment: Does it only do that with DUAL? Or also with a three-row table with test data? Can you get execution plans? And try the same on other Oracle versions?

Comment: Why do you think the trigger has something to do with this? You are inserting into T1, not V1_T1.

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski - good spot. Please post that as an answer so it can be upvoted.

Comment: I mention the trigger, because we could insert into the table directly without problems, but as we used the trigger, the problem occured. One thing I will definitely do, is to test, if my simplifications changed the behaviour and made influence on the outcome. As far as I can tell for now, the problem does not occur, if you insert directly into a table, using the mentioned INSERT statements.

Comment: @MarcinWroblewski - Of course, you are right. This is a mistake in my examples. I insert into the view. I corrected this in my answer. Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Could you also show the definition of the view?

Comment: Another possible edit on the answer should be done on `INSERT INTO Table T1 (` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does look like a bug, but I can't find an obvious match in the bug database (a few look possible, like 5842445, but are vague or don't quite line up). I can only make it happen with the trigger (so I assume your inserts being against `T1` rather than `V1_T1` are a transcription error); and only if `F4` and `F5` are `CHAR` not `VARCHAR2`:

```
create table t1 (f1 varchar2(2), f2 varchar2(2), f3 varchar2(3),
    f4 char(2), f5 char(2));

create view v1_t1 as select * from t1;
```

... and the `instead of` trigger exactly as shown in the question.

The `:NEW` values inside the trigger are wrong, according to `DBMS_OUTPUT`, but how that's affected by the column data type is something only Oracle would be able to figure out I think.

It also still happens in 11.2.0.3 (Linux). Interestingly if I change the `UNION ALL` to just `UNION` I get slightly different results; in 10g the two columns end up null, in 11g they have `x`:

```
insert into v1_t1 (
  F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
)
SELECT A.V, A.S, A.F, A.T, A.Z
FROM (
    SELECT 'E' V, 'N' S, 'ABC' F, 'E' T, 'E' Z FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'E',   'Y',   'QWE',   'O',   'E'   FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'I',   'Y',   'GHJ',   'I',   'I'   FROM DUAL
) A
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

3 rows created.

select * from v1_t1;

F1 F2 F3  F4 F5
-- -- --- -- --
E  N  ABC x  x
E  Y  QWE x  x
I  Y  GHJ x  x
```

... which is even stranger - looks like maybe a fix to some other bug has slightly affected this one.

So not really an answer; you'd need to rase a service request with Oracle, and I'm fairly sure they'd just tell you to remove the `order by` since it doesn't have any value, as you already know.

For Thilo; plan without any `order by` (11g):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |       |     3 |    51 |     9  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | V1_T1 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   VIEW                   |       |     3 |    51 |     9  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE           |       |     3 |       |     9  (78)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL            |       |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      FAST DUAL           |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      FAST DUAL           |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |      FAST DUAL           |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And plan with `order by 1,2,3` *or* `1,2,3,4,5` - same plan hash value (11g):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT         |       |     3 |    51 |    10  (40)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL | V1_T1 |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   SORT ORDER BY          |       |     3 |    51 |    10  (40)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    VIEW                  |       |     3 |    51 |     9  (34)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     SORT UNIQUE          |       |     3 |       |     9  (78)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      UNION-ALL           |       |       |       |            |          |
|   6 |       FAST DUAL          |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |       FAST DUAL          |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |       FAST DUAL          |       |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And I see the same sort of corruption selecting from other tables, but only if the results in the subquery are unioned before being ordered; though then I get nulls rather than `x`. (I briefly wondered if the `x` was coming from `dual` itself, but `dummy` is upper-case `X`, and this shows lower-case `x`).

---

Following @Annjawn's comment, changing the insert from `V1_T1` to a direct insert in `T1` works fine (i.e. correct values inserted), and curiously has the same plan hash even though it shows the table name instead of the view in the `Name` column. Work with either `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, too, and in both 10gR2 and 11gR2. Seems to be the trigger that's confused by the union, I guess.

---

Further to the datatype point... the view has to have `char` columns, the table does not necessarily, which isn't really a surprise since the trigger on the view seems to be the problem. If I set the table up with `char` columns but cast them to `varchar2` in the view then I don't see the problem:

```
create table t1 (f1 varchar2(2), f2 varchar2(2), f3 varchar2(3),
    f4 char(2), f5 char(2));

create view v1_t1 as select f1, f2, f3, cast(f4 as varchar(2)) f4,
    cast(f5 as varchar(2)) f5
from t1;
```

But If I do it the other way around it does exhibit the problem:

```
create table t1 (f1 varchar2(2), f2 varchar2(2), f3 varchar2(3),
    f4 varchar(2), f5 varchar(2));

create view v1_t1 as select f1, f2, f3, cast(f4 as char(2)) f4,
    cast(f5 as char(2)) f5
from t1;
```

Comment: Excellent research. Please link this in your bug report to Oracle (if you make one), and also update this thread with the bug ID.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, this entire ordeal works fine and inserts the rows into table `T1` as expected in both Oracle 10g and 11g.

```
create table t1 (f1 varchar2(10),
f2 varchar2(10),
f3 varchar2(10),
f4 varchar2(10),
f5 varchar2(10));

create or replace view v_t1 as select * from t1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER V1_T1_BIUD
  INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON v_t1
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  AnyId   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO t1 (
       F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
    ) VALUES (
       :new.F1, :new.F2, :new.F3, :new.F4, :new.F5
    );
  ELSIF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE t1 SET F1 = :new.F1,
                  F2 = :new.F2,
                  F3 = :new.F3,
                  F4 = :new.F4,
                  F5 = :new.F5
    WHERE F1 = :old.F1;
  ELSIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM t1
    WHERE F1 = :old.F1;
  END IF;
END;

--With UNION ALL
INSERT INTO V_T1 (
  F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
)
SELECT A.V, A.S, A.F, A.T, A.Z
FROM (
  SELECT 'E' V, 'N' S, 'ABC' F, 'E' T, 'E' Z FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'E',   'Y',   'QWE',   'O',   'E'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I',   'Y',   'GHJ',   'I',   'I'   FROM DUAL           
) A
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;

commit;

select * from t1;

F1         F2         F3         F4         F5       
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
E          N          ABC        E          E          
E          Y          QWE        O          E          
I          Y          GHJ        I          I 

delete from t1;
commit;

--With UNION
INSERT INTO V_T1 (
  F1, F2, F3, F4, F5
)
SELECT A.V, A.S, A.F, A.T, A.Z
FROM (
  SELECT 'E' V, 'N' S, 'ABC' F, 'E' T, 'E' Z FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'E',   'Y',   'QWE',   'O',   'E'   FROM DUAL UNION
  SELECT 'I',   'Y',   'GHJ',   'I',   'I'   FROM DUAL           
) A
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3; 
commit;

select * from t1;

F1         F2         F3         F4         F5       
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
E          N          ABC        E          E          
E          Y          QWE        O          E          
I          Y          GHJ        I          I
```

Sure enough, when I change `F4` and `F5` to `char(10)` from `varchar2(10)` (as noted by [Alex Poole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266304/alex-poole)) I can re-create your issue exactly in both 10g and 11g.

Comment: Yes, with the way you built the table; but as I noted in my answer, the problem manifests if `F4` and `F5` are defined as `CHAR` rather than `VARCHAR2`. Of course we don't have any confirmation that's the case for the OP, but that's the only way I could make it fail...

Comment: When I change `F4` and `F5` to `char` I can exactly re-create OP's issue.